# C: convert a mathematical expression string into an int with the result

Tags: c

I have an issue with a program: the task is to write down a function that, given a string with only numbers and `+` or `-` symbols; return the result of the expression in the `int` value.

I mean, given the input `char="2+1+3"` the result should be `int=6`.
I thought about using `strtok` to divide it into tokens and then convert them into numbers;

Do anyone have some kind of suggestion? 
I'm a first year student so i'm not quite used to complicate things, and moreover I can use only standard library.
Thanks to all.

```
int string_expression(char s1[]){
  int i;
  char*pch;
  char* frase_dup=strdup(s1);
  int count=0;
  char**dupl;
  long int pcf;
  pch=strtok(frase_dup,"+");
  pcf=strtol(const char *pch, char **dubl, int 10);

  for(i=0; i<strlen(s1); i++) {
    if(s[i]=="-")  count=count+pcf[i+1]*-1;
    if(s[i]!=NULL) count=count+pcf[i];
  }
  return count;
}
```

Of course this code is all wrong, but as i said, i'm a newbie :(

Comment: my suggestion: write some code :P

Comment: There's a worked example in Kernighan and Ritchie that covers this.

Comment: **Warning** -- If the next assignment is to process `*` and `/`, merely doing `strtok`'s is not going to help much, given that you have an order of operations to consider.

Comment: Ah, nice that @Bathsheba mentions it: Buy that book. If you are sometimes on Linux or a Unix, also buy Kernighan and Pike's [The Unix Programming Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_Programming_Environment), which is similarily good. If you don't have money, copy it in a copy shop or look for online PDFs. Yes, it's not nice, but you can always buy it later (I have). If you do anything more in-depth with your box, consider buying [Stevens' Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment) as well.

Comment: sum of do strtol each number.

Comment: That function leaks memory every time it's called due to the `strdup` call.  You're responsible for calling `free()` to deallocate the memory.

Comment: @Paul will the OP live to see an effect from that? ;-) But you are right.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It is poorly written if it leaks memory.   Imagine if that function were called in a loop, processing expressions from a file, and there are millions of expressions.  No need to introduce bad habits to a newbie.

Comment: You are trying to write a calculator. Start by googling stuff like "how to write a calculator in C".

Comment: See: https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is only addition and subtraction (white-space is not included)
It is may be just summed to convert from a string by using [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) each of the numerical value as a sequence of numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int string_expression(char s1[]){
//only numbers and + or - symbols
    char *endp = s1;
    int sum = 0;
    while(*s1){
        sum += strtol(s1, &endp, 10);
        s1 = endp;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void){
    printf("result = %d\n", string_expression("2-1+3"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't knew the correct application of strtol, now i get it.
Just a couple of questions: The while calls a pointer to s1, why? And also, why you assign s1=endp?
Thanks again :)

Comment: @Shankher `s1` is the beginning of the string to be parsed.
`endp` is the failed position in the analysis.
`s1 = endp;`  is a need to be updated for the next analysis.

Comment: Ah okay okay, so updating s1 means that the loop can continue.

Answer (score 0):

User `strtol` to parse the next number. Then check the next operation. Rinse and repeat. Here is how you could do that in pseudocode:

1. *operation* ← `'+'`, *accumulator* ← 0, *ptr* ← beginning of text
2. *summand* ← *strtol* (*ptr*, &*ptr*, 10)
3. **if** *operation* ≡ `'+'` **then** *accumulator* ← *accumulator* + *summand*
   **else** **if** *operation* ≡ `'-'` **then** *accumulator* ← *accumulator* − *summand*
   **else** expression is malformed.
4. *operation* ← **ptr*, *ptr* ← *ptr* + 1
5. **if** *operation* ≡ `'\0'` **then** **return** *accumulator*.
6. **goto** step 2

Answer (score 0):

You'll later need to code some [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) (and perhaps before a lexical tokenizer or [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)). This is a very classical exercise.
You could hand-code some [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or use some parser generator tool (a.k.a [compiler-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler), somehow incorrectly because a compiler is a lot more than parsing).
The [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) tool has your exercise as an example in its documentation.

You might want (at least for fun) to explicitly construct an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in memory before evaluating it.

So you could "steal" some code found on the Web quite easily, but you will *learn a lot more* by doing it yourself. Learning programming takes a lot of time ([ten years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) perhaps).