# Is there any C function that can evalute a string expression defined in the standard library?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, integer, expression

I am looking for a function that can evaluate a string expression into an integer, like f.e.:

```
10/2+4*3-(12+5); //Equals 0
```

into an object of type `int` with the value of `0`.

A function for complex operation would be preferable even though that's not the need of the hour:

```
2^(1/2)-99
```

---

Is there any such definition defined in the standard C library (C89, C90, if it's compiled)?

Is there any non-standard library which has such an function?

The more the characters the expression supports the better it is.

But even basic operation like +,-,*,/,() would do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207951/discussion-on-question-by-hello-world-is-there-any-c-function-that-can-evalute-a).

Comment: No such function exists.  For the next time, you can answer such questions yourself by reading the documentation supplied with the standard library of your C implementation vendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any such definition defined in the standard C library (C89, C90, if it's compiled)?

No, not even in the more recent standard libraries of C11 or C18.

> Is there any non-standard library which has such an function?

I couldn´t found one either. You have to write your own function to accomplish that.

Maybe scan the string and store every value in it to a separate string at the first step.

As I already suggested in the comments, `strtol` is used to convert an integer value like `11` in a string to a value of type `int`. You might need to take use of that. In the libraries there is also a function of `atoi` to convert an integer value inside a string to an `int` but this function is more susceptible for errors and should not be used.

The arithmetic operators shall be stored in separate strings also, but later evaluated by a self-made routine.

But good examples and recommendations can be found here, where a user have been asked a similar (if not the same) question:

[C: convert a mathematical expression string into an int with the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059200/c-convert-a-mathematical-expression-string-into-an-int-with-the-result)

Answer (score 3):

There is no function in the Standard C library to evaluation arithmetic expressions. Here is a quick and dirty implementation of an `evald` function for `double` result. It supports the 5 classical binary operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%` and the exponentiation with `^`, handles any depth of parentheses but needs more work for unary `+` and `-`.

It is easy to convert to integer only arithmetic.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double evald(const char *s, char **endp) {
    struct operand {
        double val;
        int op, prec;
    } stack[4], *sp, x;
    char *p;

    for (sp = stack;;) {
        if (*s == '(') {
            x.val = evald(s + 1, &p);
            s = p;
            if (*s == ')')
                s++;
        } else {
            x.val = strtod(s, &p);
            s = p;
        }
        while (isspace((unsigned char)*s))
            s++;
        switch (x.op = *s++) {
        case '^': x.prec = 3; break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%': x.prec = 2; break;
        case '+':
        case '-': x.prec = 1; break;
        default:  x.prec = 0; x.op = 0; s--; break;
        }
        while (sp > stack && x.prec <= sp[-1].prec) {
            switch ((--sp)->op) {
            case '^': x.val = pow(sp->val, x.val); break;
            case '*': x.val = sp->val * x.val; break;
            case '/': x.val = sp->val / x.val; break;
            case '%': x.val = fmod(sp->val, x.val); break;
            case '+': x.val = sp->val + x.val; break;
            case '-': x.val = sp->val - x.val; break;
            }
        }
        if (!x.op) break;
        *sp++ = x;
    }
    if (endp) *endp = (char *)s;
    return x.val;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%s -> %.17g\n", argv[i], evald(argv[i], NULL));
        }
    } else {
        char buf[100];
        for (;;) {
            printf("eval> ");
            fflush(stdout);
            if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) || (buf[0] == 'q' && buf[1] == '\n'))
                break;
            printf(" -> %.17g\n", evald(buf, NULL));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually I was looking for a efficient function that has it's RnD done on it. You could spend some time and make a super efficient code and then make it a part of an existing library or create your own library with some more functions and then post it's link in the form of an answer, if you wish to.

Comment: @HelloWorld Is this code critical for the performance of your program?  If not, I recommend you to lower your expectations and use any code that works instead of demanding perfection.  What chqrlie wrote doesn't look too bad though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any non-standard library which has such an function?

[GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) has such an example. `bison` is a [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) and is a [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) tool generating C files.

You could also use and embed [Lua](https://lua.org/) in your application. It is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), so you should study its source code. Lua is mostly coded in standard C99.

You could code your own [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), quite simple to do.

You could consider embedding [GNU Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org/) in your application.

Of course, you should use a better operating system than the obsolete MS-DOS (or its [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) alternative). [Debian](https://debian.org/) comes to mind.

You could use [tinycc](https://repo.or.cz/tinycc.git), it has a library (`libtcc`) similar to your needs and you can study its source code.

You need to read textbooks about parsing and compiling. The [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) comes to mind. Or at least read the wikipedia page on [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and on [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I added unary operators to RobertS's parser. On first entry or recursive to parse what's inside ()' just before the loop you push a 0 onto the stack, at highest priority along with the operator. Then it can handle: -(2-5)^2 which is -(-3) and then squared for 9 or even -((2-5)**2) and get a -9 for the value. Each stack push puts a value/operator (in that order) onto the stack, and compares the next pair with the top of the stack. (Took me a while get the hang of this algorithm).

Also, you can add functions by treating them as simply ()'s that once recursively evaluated, are run though the function before being pushed onto the stack.

```
  c = *s;
  if (c  == '+' || c == '-') { // check for initial uniary+ or - 
        x.val = 0.0;
        x.op  = c;
        x.prec = 3;  // give it highest priority
        *sp++ = x;  // pretend we started with a 0, so it's 0+... or 0-...
        s++;
    }
```

A full-on expansion of this algorithm can now be found here:

https://github.com/rocketship88/expression